# In Flex mobile app, can I stream local video file to rtmp server

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript, stream

I have a video file in external storage of phone.
Can I stream it to RTMP server directly?

Currently, I'm only able to stream camera to server successfully:

```
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.attachCamera(cam);
ns.attachAudio(mic);
ns.publish("my_rtmp_streaming_server_url", "live");
```

Comment: Can you find any solution for that. I looking for same thing here.